# draw a curve Sketchup using ruby

Tags: ruby, graphics, sketchup

Below are some point 3d:

> 15.733798,20.019757,23.006311 15.733798,19.847666,23.006311
>   15.723798,19.847666,23.006311 15.723798,20.019757,23.006311
>   15.733798,20.019757,23.006311

and this is a vector

> 0.0,0.0,-0.1

Is it possible to draw a curve from the information above in sketchup?

Answer (score 0):

What is it that the 3d points represent?

You mention "curve" - but do you mean arc?
You can create curves with a set of arbitrary Point3d - but for arcs you need center point, radius and vector and angles.